# In Django, charfield avoid character duplicates

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my model, dosage field is there.
I added data like this, dosage field = 100mg
If i try to add data like this, dosage field = 100 mg
It should not get add.
Same way, I added data like this, dosage field = 20 mg
If i try to add data like this, dosage field = 20mg
It should not get add. It's like vice versa.
How to avoid this.

Comment: Let me try to understand the challenge here. You don't want to allow updating the data after its added?

Comment: Not only update, it should not allow duplicate in different format. LIke 1st row, drug_name = crocin,  dosage = 10mg. If someone trying to add, 2nd row , drug_name = crocin, dosage = 10 mg. 2nd row shouldn't add.